# CSS Hamburger menu opening on top of next div

Tags: html, css, menu, hamburger-menu

I created a hamburger CSS only menu and everything seems to be working ok, except for the fact that when I try to open it, the menu elements appear on top of the next element in the HTML code (the next div). The full code is here: https://codepen.io/Cilvako/pen/wjwmJP

I feel like I'm missing something but I can't figure it out what is it that I'm doing wrong.

```
  <header>
        <div class="nav">
            <h1>Zero Gravity</h1>

                 <label for="toggle">&#9776</label>
                 <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>

          <div class="menu">
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
                <a href="#"><span>Free Trial</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>

   <div class="main_content">
       <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet short ribs tri-tip porchetta rump leberkas cupim shank turkey. Biltong hamburger jerky, ball tip sausage cupim tongue t-bone leberkas. Tri-tip porchetta jerky frankfurter shankle kevin andouille tail beef chuck swine sirloin strip steak corned beef. Meatloaf ham hock landjaeger kielbasa ribeye t-bone.</p>

   </div>
```

Comment: Remove the height from your nav or change it to a min-height: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvBvje

Comment: .menu {float: left;} , just add this to the `.menu` css and done. The problem with the above comment is it wil take up a border 2times, look at the bottom of the menu when opened on his codepen, but up 2 you

Comment: @Pete adding a min-height worked wonders, thank you. Can you explain what difference did it make in the behavior of the code?

Comment: @Ylama not that you mentioned it, I also noticed the double line at the bottom. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing i did was adding `float: left;` to the class --> `menu` .

In this case it would take up the full width space , also it wont dupicate the menu border line.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  heigth: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00b3b3;
  text-align: right;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;

}

.nav h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #00b3b3;
  
}

.menu {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  clear: both;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00b3b3;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  line-height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00b3b3;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 26px;
  float: right;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked + .menu {
    display: block;
  }

.main_content {
  clear: both;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="nav">
        <h1>Zero Gravity</h1>
  
       <label for="toggle">&#9776</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
  
     <div class="menu">
           <a href="#">About Us</a>
           <a href="#">Contact</a>
           <a href="#">Blog</a>
           <a href="#"><span>Free Trial</span></a>
     </div>
      </div>
  </header>

<div class="main_content">
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet short ribs tri-tip porchetta rump leberkas cupim shank turkey. Biltong hamburger jerky, ball tip sausage cupim tongue t-bone leberkas. Tri-tip porchetta jerky frankfurter shankle kevin andouille tail beef chuck swine sirloin strip steak corned beef. Meatloaf ham hock landjaeger kielbasa ribeye t-bone.</p>
    </br>
  <p>Jerky doner leberkas corned beef ham pork chop. T-bone frankfurter meatloaf beef, tail pancetta brisket spare ribs ribeye boudin jowl pork chop swine turducken venison. Pancetta cow venison tail tenderloin alcatra buffalo boudin capicola salami porchetta swine. Pork loin shankle ground round brisket burgdoggen bresaola capicola, chicken porchetta venison. Drumstick tenderloin porchetta, alcatra kielbasa rump picanha venison doner. Kevin ribeye capicola, chicken prosciutto strip steak meatball. Porchetta sausage shank, meatball andouille ham hock jowl t-bone. Spare ribs ball tip pancetta, frankfurter corned beef kielbasa shankle. Beef ribs porchetta t-bone capicola tail jowl flank rump drumstick. Bresaola filet mignon shoulder, prosciutto salami kielbasa cow chuck tail venison leberkas tenderloin.</p>
    </br>
  <p>Biltong short loin porchetta meatloaf pancetta. Kevin swine ham shankle, short ribs corned beef bresaola. Cupim pork kielbasa pork loin hamburger ribeye. Ham hamburger short loin chuck. Leberkas alcatra t-bone frankfurter kielbasa pastrami turducken. Hamburger shoulder swine capicola, brisket alcatra meatloaf rump chuck shank salami cupim kevin porchetta burgdoggen. Short ribs short loin tri-tip burgdoggen. Kevin ribeye capicola, chicken prosciutto strip steak meatball. Porchetta sausage shank, meatball andouille ham hock jowl t-bone. Spare ribs ball tip pancetta, frankfurter corned beef kielbasa shankle. Beef ribs porchetta t-bone capicola tail jowl flank rump drumstick. Bresaola filet mignon shoulder, prosciutto salami kielbasa cow chuck tail venison leberkas tenderloin.</p>
  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you want your menu to function.  You're displaying it with CSS rather than using any JS, which I think is pretty nice and lightweight.  On that basis, I would suggest that you set the menu to simply sit over the existing content (as it does) and have a solid background colour (as it currently doesn't).  You can set the background colour on `.menu` with the `background-color` CSS property, and you'll also need to add `position: relative` to make sure it displays as you want it to.

I've made you a codepen to see it in action:
http://jsbin.com/remadowagu/edit?html,css,output

If you don't want to display your menu on top of your content, and would rather your content moves down below the menu, then Pete's answer above will solve this for you.  However, my personal preference would be to overlay the page content with the menu rather than push it down.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to club the elements in `menu` for eg `menu-a` and then use the `display: inline-block` in the CSS code.

The menu code should look a little bit like this:

```
<div class="menu">
  <a class="menu-a" href="#">About Us</a>
  <a class="menu-a" href="#">Contact</a>
  <a class="menu-a" href="#">Blog</a>
  <a class="menu-a" href="#"><span>Free Trial</span></a>
</div>
```

And add the below to the CSS code:

```
menu-a {
  display: inline-block
}
```